# Error on convertion of java.util.Map to JSON in JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, moxy

My program works fine with conversion of List to JSON but it returns error on conversion of Map to JSON.

I have provided my code below

```java
@Path("demo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class Demo 
{
    @GET
    public Map<String, String> display()
    {
        Map<String,String> names=new HashMap();

        names.put("name1", "foo");
        names.put("name2","foo2");
        return names;
    }
}
```

I have added following dependencies in my pom.xml to support JSON conversion.

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I am getting follwing error

> Jun 26, 2017 3:55:34 AM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
>   SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.HashMap, genericType=java.util.Map.

How to fix this error? which dependencies i should add to support conversion of Map to JSON?

Comment: try this dependency  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Use this dependency 

`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: Still having same error even I've added dependencies you mentioned

Comment: Remove moxy after adding jackson

Comment: Tnx @peeskillet your solution worked for me. I had to remove Moxy dependency to get error free output.